# GET JSON response, parse it and then convert back to a JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, httprequest, httpresponse

My goal is;

1. GET a JSON file from an API and make changes to the data
2. Then generate a new dictionary from this data
3. Convert this dictionary into JSON

So far I have points 1 and 2 complete but struggling to understand how I can convert the changes into a new JSON

```
Main.java

//get JSON from API
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")).build();
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                //.thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .thenApply(Main::parse)
                .join();
    }
//Parse Json
    public static String parse(String responseBody) {
        JSONArray albums = new JSONArray(responseBody);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < albums.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = album.getInt("id");
            int userId = album.getInt("userId");
            String title = album.getString("title");
            System.out.println("id: " + id);
            System.out.println("userId: " + userId);
            System.out.println("title: " + title);

        }
        return null;
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the library that contains `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`, but I've seen quite a few libraries where the `toString()` method returns the JSON you're looking for.

Comment: Im new with JSON so not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @JoeyOC what's the package of class `JSONArray`?

Comment: `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONObject` are the two libraries

Comment: That's the one I found yesterday. Its documentation is available at https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html. It says for `toString()`: "Make a JSON text of this JSONArray." In other words, just call `toString()` and you get JSON. You can also call `toString(2)` to get an indentation of 2 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`org.json` is a simple library. It is possible to do what you want with this library but I can offer you much simpler solution. Your code may look something like this:

```
public static String parse(String responseBody) {
   List<Map<String, Object>> myList = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(responseBody, List.class); //here you get a list of Maps that contasins your data
   //Here you modify your data
   return JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(myList); //Here you convert your modified list of maps mack to Json String
 }
```

You will need to get MgntUtils library to use `JsonUtils` class. You can get the library as maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or as just a jar file [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Here is Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class